# Read json file continuously

Tags: r, file, shiny, reactive

I want to read a json file continuously, e.g. every 1000 ms.

1. One option my be reactiveFileReader

`reactiveFileReader(intervalMillis, session, filePath, readFunc, ...)`

described [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/reactiveFileReader.html).
This function seems only working with csv files and not for json files:

```
file_data <- reactiveFileReader(intervalMillis = 1000, NULL, filePath = json_path, readFunc = read.json)

  observe({
    View(file_data())
  })
```

```
Error in View : object read.json not found
```

2. With reactivePoll like here:

```
getJsonData <- reactivePoll(1000, session,
                                  checkFunc = function() {
                                      if (file.exists(path))
                                          file.info(path)$mtime[1]
                                      else
                                          ""
                                   },
                                   valueFunc = function() {
                                       read_json(path)
                                   }
```

I get nearly what I want, but this function is not working in my context. How do I force the program to read the file every second and not only when the content of the file is changing?

Are there other possibilities I not have thought about yet?

Comment: Not very clean, but instead of `file.info(path)$mtime[1]`, you could return a random number.

Comment: I think `reactiveFileReader` is the right approach, however as @StéphaneLaurent already implied, there is no `read.json` function in base R.

Comment: Try `invalidateLater` function (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53455448/how-do-i-make-a-shiny-app-read-continuously-from-a-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first way, you wrote `read.json` instead of `read_json`.

With your second way, you could replace `file.info(path)$mtime[1]` with `runif(1, 0, 1e6)`. You would be very unlucky if `runif` returns the same number two consecutive times.

Finally, a third way could be:

```
server <- function(input, output, session){

  autoInvalidate <- reactiveTimer(1000)

  getJsonData <- reactive({
    autoInvalidate()
    read_json("path/to/file.json")
  })

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reprex on how to use `reactiveFileReader` with a json file.

I used a `future` to detach the writing process from the shiny session - you can simply replace this with your json input.

```
library(shiny)
library(jsonlite)
library(datasets)
library(promises)
library(future)

plan(multisession(workers = 2))

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("printResult")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  json_path <- tempfile(fileext = ".json")
  write_json(NULL, json_path)

  # async file writing process
  future({
    for(i in seq_len(nrow(iris))){
      Sys.sleep(1)
      write_json(iris[i,], json_path)
    }
  })

  file_data <- reactiveFileReader(intervalMillis = 1000, NULL, filePath = json_path, readFunc = read_json)

  output$printResult <- renderUI({
    req(file_data())
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Result]